# htaccess redirect subfolder to subdomain

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm running Apache mod_rewrite on a Linux server and I need to redirect a subfolder to a sub-domain and remove the subfolder from the url. For example:

http://www.mydomain.com/forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=11816&PID=252908&title=pouch-information-day-the-next-one#252908

needs to redirect to

http://subdomain.mydomain.com/forum_posts.asp?TID=11816&PID=252908&title=pouch-information-day-the-next-one#252908

Please can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

The [Apache URL Rewriting Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) is a great reference. This is how I would do it:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} ^www.mydomain.com/forum/
RewriteRule ^/forum/(.*) http://subdomain.mydomain.com/$1 [L,R]
```